В manifest.json start_url открывает не тот файл
Всем привет! Разрабатываю свое pwa приложение. Есть проблема, при открытии pwa приложения через кнопку на сайте, оно открывает ту страницу, на которой кнопка, хотя в manifest.json в параметре start_url указана другая страница.
Помогите!!
manifest.json
{
    "name": "My PWA",
    "short_name": "PWA",
    "description": "Пример Progressive Web Application",
    "start_url": "/index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#ffaae9",
    "theme_color": "#ffaae9",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "html/assets/img/icon192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "html/assets/img/icon512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "html/assets/img/icon144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
      }
    ]
  }
  

service-worker.js
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('Service Worker installing.');
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open('my-cache').then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll([
          '/',
          '/index.html',
          '/html/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          '/html/assets/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css',
          '/html/assets/css/magnific-popup.css',
          '/html/assets/css/style.css',
          '/html/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
          '/html/assets/js/popper.min.js',
          '/html/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
          '/html/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js',
          '/html/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
          '/html/assets/js/jquery.countdown.min.js',
          '/html/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js',
          '/html/assets/js/jquery-validate.bootstrap-tooltip.min.js',
          '/html/assets/js/custom.js',
          '/html/assets/img/icon144.png',
          '/html/assets/img/icon192.png',
          '/html/assets/img/icon512.png'
        ]).then(function() {
          console.log('All resources have been cached successfully.');
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error('Cache addAll failed:', error);
        });
      })
    );
  });
  
  self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('Service Worker activating.');
  });

  self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
  });

index-dark-shapes-cta.html
  <!-- Регистрация Service Worker -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(error) {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', error);
        });
      });
    }
  </script>

    <!-- Обработка установки PWA -->
    <script>
        let deferredPrompt;
    
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          deferredPrompt = e;
          document.getElementById('install-btn').style.display = 'inline-block'; // Устанавливаем inline-block для правильного отображения
        });
    
        document.getElementById('install-btn').addEventListener('click', async () => {
          if (deferredPrompt) {
            deferredPrompt.prompt();
            const { outcome } = await deferredPrompt.userChoice;
            if (outcome === 'accepted') {
              console.log('User accepted the install prompt');
            } else {
              console.log('User dismissed the install prompt');
            }
            deferredPrompt = null;
          }
        });
      </script>

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <title>My PWA</title>
  <!-- Другие теги head -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Контент вашего PWA -->
   123
   123
   123
   123

   <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>

